# wget website recusively from localhost without using bandwith

Tags: apache-2.4, wordpress, wget, static-content

i'm looking to download recusively my wordpress website into static using wget, the problem is that whenever i do that, it's using too much bandwith (3.5gb) even though i end up downloading 20mb which weird, so i'm looking to download using localhost, but when i use wget with localhost i only get the index page, now, we all know that wordpress saves the website url into database, so how am i supposed to download using localhost, i already set it up in apache configuration, i just want to download without using so many bandwith.

Tried using -N option to reduce bandwith but i keep getting error that files don't have last-modified header, so it is not helping..

This is the command i'm using :

```
wget -N     --recursive      --no-clobber      --page-requisites      --html-extension      --convert-links      --restrict-file-names=windows      --domains website website -P /opt/
```

Thank you,

UPDATE 1 :
Used /etc/hosts and linked the website to the localhost ip 127.0.0.1, but still it redirects back to the original ip and even then only downloads the index.page.

Is there a way to tell server to force add last-modified header to all wordpress files ?

Comment: Use the /etc/hosts file and map the FQDN your Wordpress uses to 127.0.0.1 and you can mirror without generating external traffic

Comment: I'm actually doing that, but it is not working, it keeps generating external traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `--page-requisites` option.

This option causes wget to download all images, CSS, scripts, etc., for each page, *including ones from external sites*. This isn't necessary for your case because all of the internal ones would already be downloaded.

---

You also should consider some more reasonable way to export your site. If you mean for it to remain static forever, and you will never again change it (which is very unlikely!) then this approach is fine. But consider instead exporting it in a format suitable for importing to a static site generator such as hugo or jekyll. By this method you can have static web pages but still be able to maintain them when it becomes necessary later.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for responding, i'm planning to update the static website which will be hosted on s3 every 1 hour, so actually, i'm planning to update very frequently, i removed the --page-requisites option, still it takes almost the same time and bandwidth, i do not know about jekyll or hugo, do they support exporting the whole wordpress in a static condition that works perfectly ?